# What is the systemd equivalent of ntsysv?

Tags: linux, systemd, rhel7

Now that RHEL 7 uses systemd the `ntsysv` tool only shows *some* of the services on my system. Is there a systemd equivalent to `ntsysv` whch will allow me to show/configure *all* services on my system?

I am a commandline only user, so I would like a TUI.

Comment: I have edited your question for clarity [based on your comment below](http://serverfault.com/questions/594530/what-is-a-good-ntsysv-replacement-now-rhel-7-uses-systemd#comment703387_594537). I have also removed the "I don't want `systemctl`" restriction -- If there is a specific reason why you cannot use `systemctl` for this please edit your question to *explain your reason for rejecting this tool as an option* - I assume you have a reason, but it's incumbent on *you* to explain it.

Comment: I have created one for systemctl. https://github.com/chunhualiu/sc

Comment: @ChunhuaLiu Very cool! Very nice overview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I had the same problem.**

I use to check the installed services using `ntsysv` (Red Hat family distros) and `rcconf` (Debian family distros). However with this new standard I was forced to find another solution. Then I found in the Arch Linux repository [**a python script to do the check**](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/serman).  I just downloaded the tarball and uncompressed it in /usr/local/bin.  I am using RHEL 7.2 and to me, it seems working fine.

To invoke the program just execute in the command-line: `serman2`

**EDITED:**
The new version of **ntsysv** now is showing systemd services (Red Hat and Cent OS 7), so just invoke **`ntsysv`** via command line.

[image]

Comment: I just found this in EL7.3 too. I was happy to see it.

Answer (score 5):

Check the [cheat sheet](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/SysVinit_to_Systemd_Cheatsheet) for native commands. But you can still use `chkconfig`. And `ntsysv` [still shows up](http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/26119664/dir/redhat_7.x/com/ntsysv-1.3.61-4.el7.x86_64.rpm.html) in the EL7 package list.

[image]

Comment: Problem with chkconfig and ntsysv is that it doesnt show all services anymore. Some are on it, some are not. Its quite confusing when chkconfig/ntsysv shows 3 services and systemctl shows a lot more.

I know how to use systemctl, but what I really want is a ntsysv TUI replacement that shows me the list graphically. Call me lazy, but for me its a must-have tool on my CentOS 6.x servers. I can go through a list of services with arrow buttons, now instead I need to use my superman laser eyes to to avoid mistakes.

Comment: Lazy much? Systems progress, progress with them or be left behind.

Comment: Its not about being lazy or not. Its about usability of a tool. I am looking for something like ntsysv, a TUI so I can go through a list of services "graphically".  Progress is subjective, for me systemd feels like a mess. My first linux distro was slackware 2.1.

Comment: @laapsaap If you have a need for this, it's a strong indicator that you are trying to do too many things with a system. Ideally each server should be dedicated to a single purpose.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Not necessarily. I have application servers out there that have a full complement of related services. I understand what the OP wants, but really, this is a one-time or infrequent task. If you have configuration management of any sort, you won't even need to go this far.

Comment: Point taken; I guess this is "Linux way" and I have to live with it. Of course there are many other ways to achieve what I want, just not the way I want to. I do use CHEF for all my servers and all my servers are single purpose, nevertheless I still liked ntsysv. Its a simple overview tool with a simple function. Systemd is like Windows 8 for me, over complicating things that we are very used to do simply; In the name of "progress" and "innovation". Uhuh.